# Check Qt4 code for backward compatibility

Tags: qt, qt4

I am wondering if there is a tool to check a Qt4 project (C++) for backward compatibility with a specific older Qt version. For example, my project uses version 4.8.4 and I would like to run it on 4.5.3.

I am thinking of a compatibility check on the basis of the source code. I would prefer a solution which does not rely on QtCreator (but please name it anyway if any ;)

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be to compile your code against 4.5.3 and also test the result - even if the API remains compatible, you can not be 100% sure that the behaviour did not change, unless you run a test cycle

Comment: You mean source compatibility or runtime compatibility? If you mean runtime compatibility then 4.8.x won't be binary compatible with 4.5.x. This means that you will have to recompile your source code with 4.5.x to make your app work with 4.5.x version of Qt

Comment: There have been many changes and bug fixes between those versions. A tool, which would check if any of those missing bug fixes would affect your program, would be quite complicated. I would do as Andreas said, compile and run tests.

Comment: @Kamil Qt garantees binary compatibiliy between major versions. But there may be other things, e.g. Added fields to enun which break your pedantic werror build.